# Objective-c extern variables changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, global-variables, extern

Please help, I'm stuck with objective-c global variables aka extern!
I writing my first iOS app it is a game, so to save my progress I wrote some global variables in Globals.h:

```
@interface Globals : NSObject
extern float square;
extern float field;
extern float dx;
extern float dy;
extern NSURL *documentsUrl;
extern NSURL *dbUrl;
extern NSString *savePath;
extern FMDatabase *db;
@end
```

And Globals.m:

```
#import "Globals.h"

@implementation Globals

float square;
float field;
float dx;
float dy;

NSURL *documentsUrl;
NSURL *dbUrl;
NSString *savePath;
FMDatabase *db;

+(void)initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if (!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        square = 177.7778;
        field = 146.0;
        dx = 105;
        dy = 58.5;

        documentsUrl = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        dbUrl = [documentsUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"alias.sql"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"alias" withExtension:@"sql"] toURL:dbUrl error:nil];
        savePath = [[documentsUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"] path];
        db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[dbUrl path]];
        //db.logsErrors = YES;
        //db.traceExecution = YES;
        if (![db open]) {
            NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I make asured that initialize method executes at least once as app launched. In MainViewController which is my RootViewController in viewDidLoad method I use:

```
[GameInfo hasSave];
```

Which is a static method in GameInfo class and look like:

```
+(BOOL)hasSave
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: savePath];
}
```

And when I trace it the savePath is something like:

> /Users/Apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/472969F1-3760-4C74-8C8D-29681F47F4CB/Documents/save.plist

But then I execute IBAction on Touch up inside in the same view, in the same time which look like:

```
if ([GameInfo hasSave])
{
    [GameInfo load];
}
```

And when I make a step in method hasSave I have some strange savePath value:

> ar.lproj

And my method of course returns me NO. But it occurs not only with my savePath, but with all other extern variables. And sometimes they are correct but sometimes they are not.
I think maybe the problem is where I use them, maybe I forgot something to do. Please help me.

P.S.: Sorry about my English and a huge quastion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: savePath];` will return `NO` as there exits the `savePath` but there doesn't exists the file as you haven't created it in

```
+(void)initialize
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ edited ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
use `extern NSString *savePath;` in your GameInfo.h or .m

Comment: I created it in other place I use [GameInfo saveGame] method when I starts new game witch looks like
+(void)save
{
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:game toFile: savePath];
}

Comment: edited and how are you using savePath in your GameInfo have you declared it there if yes then how?

Comment: I imported Blobals.h where I declare extern NSString *savePath,  so I think this is enough. Isn't it?

Comment: yes it is... also try this comment all externs from Globals.h

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate junk values, you should initialize your global variables in their instantiation:

```
NSString *mySavePathString = nil;
```

You also need to make sure that any objects assigned to global variables are explicitly retained (and released). (Was there any retain in your sample?)

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand your question. Did you meen I need to retain savePath like savePath = [[[documentsUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"] path] retain];

Comment: Yes.  That will prevent the auto-released object from being released, thus potentially reused and trashed.